# Can I see enemy mines in BF3?

Tags: battlefield-3

I can see friendly mines on my HUD and on the ground, but haven't ever noticed if I could see enemy mines (before I was blown sky high).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can see them, even without the night vision. You can see the 3d model of the tanks mines, though they can be hard to spot when driving fast.

Se this wiki, that has pictures of them:

http://battlefield.wikia.com/wiki/IRNV_scope

Answer (score 4):

The only way to make enemy mines more noticeable is to use one of the night vision (infra-red) views. This can be either the IRNV 1x Scope that most weapons have, or the thermal optic perk that many vehicles have (I'm pretty sure all ground vehicles with upgrades can use it).

Using these two methods, enemy mines will show up as yellow with a gun, and white with a vehicle.

Answer (score 0):

It does not work for Xbox. If you have thermal optics enabled the mines does not glow white. 
I am not sure if its a glitch for Xbox.